# Windows host shares doesn't get mount when I boot into Linux guest in vmware?

Tags: linux, windows, vmware

I've enable network shares in vmware and I want to share a Windows folder with my Linux guest OS but I don't know where to look in my guest OS? In Linux I've looked into network shares and samba shares to no avail. My Linux is a standard installation of Suse 12.1.

Comment: What VMware are you running? Player, Workstation, Server, ESX, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I also faced the same problem. I solved it by mounting that shared directory in Linux by using the `mount` command:

`$ mount -t cifs -o username="user",password="passwd" //172.31.100.1/share /media`

where `user` is the username of any of the Windows user,`passwd` is the password of `user`,`172.31.100.1` is the ip address of the Windows machine,`share` is the directory to be shared,`media` is the place you want to mount.

**EDIT:** Before doing all this you have to confirm that the windows host and linux are able to communicate. This you can do by using [Host-Only Network Configuration](http://www.vmware.com/support/ws55/doc/ws_net_configurations_hostonly.html) in Vmware.

Then you can check whether both are able to ping each other or not.

Comment: This may work but how do I know the ip address of my Windows host? It's not a vmware server installation but it's neither 127.0.0.1, isn't it?

Comment: @David: You can find out the ip address by using `ipconfig` command. I have edited the answer, you can once try and if not successful, I will give edit my answer again with detailed explanation.

Comment: I've found this link http://www.linuxforums.org/forum/suse-linux/69669-vmware-suse-10-1-mount-windows.html. Do I need to install vmware tools? I don't have /mnt/hpfs in my guest?

Comment: According to [this KB article](http://www.vmware.com/support/ws5/doc/ws_running_sharedfolder_viewing.html) the host IP should be known by using the name `.host`.